# How to change float precision inside a KML file via sed commands without changing its structure

Tags: bash, sed, kml

I have a kml file (short example bellow, the real one is hundreds of lines bigger) with float numbers and strings. I'd like to change the precision of float numbers using SED or AWK commands only (to 4 digits after decimal point, for instance), without touching the structure of the file itself and the remaining strings. I have tried awk, grep and sed but ended up selecting the number only. Someone can help me on this task ?

```
        <Placemark>
                <name>Line 276</name>
                <styleUrl>#st-9324-0</styleUrl>
                <LineString>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>
                        -82.0843550361,-10.3436718895,0
                        -82.0733687247,-10.3414798573,0
                        -82.067875569,-10.3436762828,0
                        -82.0623824134,-10.3464215529,0
                        -82.051396102,-10.354657111,0
                        -82.0513917085,-10.3546626018,0
                        -82.0470007396,-10.3656489207,0
                        -82.0470007396,-10.3766352397,0
                        -82.0491996781,-10.3876215586,0
                        -82.051396102,-10.3912813368,0
                        -82.0568892577,-10.3986078776,0
                        -82.0623824134,-10.4030032431,0
                        -82.0706234567,-10.4095941965,0
                        -82.0733687247,-10.4114246674,0
                        -82.0843550361,-10.4169172451,0
                        -82.0953303765,-10.4205805155,0
                        -82.0953413474,-10.4205832616,0
                        -82.1063276588,-10.4219531504,0
                        -82.1173139701,-10.4219531504,0
                        -82.1209737457,-10.4205805155,0
                        -82.1283002815,-10.41618515,0
                        -82.1337934371,-10.4095941965,0
                        -82.1345777463,-10.3986078776,0
                        -82.1324208031,-10.3876215586,0
                        -82.1283002815,-10.3793805097,0
                        -82.1261038575,-10.3766352397,0
                        -82.1173139701,-10.3678453462,0
                        -82.1151175462,-10.3656489207,0
                        -82.1063276588,-10.3583258722,0
                        -82.1008345031,-10.3546626018,0
                        -82.0953413474,-10.3502672363,0
                        -82.0843623548,-10.3436762828,0
                        -82.0843550361,-10.3436718895,0
                    </coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>                    
                    <Placemark>
                            <name>12</name>
                            <styleUrl>#st-9325-0</styleUrl>
                            <Point>
                                    <coordinates>
                                    -80.881497121,-43.7490060037,0
                                    </coordinates>
                           </Point>
                    </Placemark>
```

Thanks.

jb

Comment: Why? [**What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: To decrease the size of the file ... Changing the precision of float numbers to 4 digits after point, and erasing all the tabulation (sed -ri s/"\tab"/""/g file), the kml file, which was originally 2.2 MB, now  has got 800 kb. For my purpose a geo position with 4 digits is more than enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the following sed command :

```
s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{4})[0-9]+/\1/g
```

It matches :

- into a first group :

  - as many digits as possible
  - a literal dot
  - four more digits
- outside of the group :

  - as many other digits as possible

It then replaces the whole match with the first group, truncating the extra digits.

With GNU sed, using `-i` to edit the file "in-place" and `-r` to avoid having to escape parentheses and `+` : `sed -ri 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{4})[0-9]+/\1/g' file`

Edit : actually we don't need to match the sign

Comment: wow. This was really fast.! Thanks a lot.! I had messed up myself with regexp inside the sed. Now I see the power of it.

Comment: careful, I had typoed an extra "\" in there (before the first `[0-9]` class)

Comment: Realize and correct it. accepted as the correct answer.! Thanks again, really.